# Can't find font as regular user

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, vim, font

As a root, I can run gvim with my font selected as 'Ubuntu mono 14' and have everything work correctly. But as a regular user using the *exact* same config file selecting the *exact* same font, I get this:

> (gvim:10498): Pango-WARNING **: 20:39:24.946: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'Ubuntu Mono 14'

> (gvim:10498): Pango-WARNING **: 20:39:24.947: font_face status is: file not found

> (gvim:10498): Pango-WARNING **: 20:39:24.947: scaled_font status is: file not found

> (gvim:10498): Pango-WARNING **: 20:39:24.952: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'Ubuntu Mono 14'

> (gvim:10498): Pango-WARNING **: 20:39:24.952: font_face status is: file not found

> (gvim:10498): Pango-WARNING **: 20:39:24.952: scaled_font status is: file not found

> (gvim:10498): Pango-WARNING **: 20:39:25.572: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'Ubuntu Mono Bold 14'

> (gvim:10498): Pango-WARNING **: 20:39:25.572: font_face status is: file not found

> (gvim:10498): Pango-WARNING **: 20:39:25.572: scaled_font status is: file not found

If I then do "fc-match 'ubuntu mono'" the response is

> UbuntuMono-R.ttf: "Ubuntu Mono" "Regular"

exactly as it should be. But still no fonts in my gvim, all I get are unicode empty glyph blocks--even for spaces!

Path is identical; config files are identical; everything I look at appears to be identical. This is driving me nuts. Please help!